# InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: request_timeout in OpenAI LLM

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api

As I am running this code block, I am getting a **request timeout error**.

Here is the code block:

```
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"]="xxxxxxxxxx"
llm = OpenAI(model_name="text-ada-001", n=2, best_of=2)
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

Here is the detailed error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

File /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py:362, in APIRequestor._interpret_response_line(self, rbody, rcode, rheaders, stream)
    360 stream_error = stream and "error" in resp.data
    361 if stream_error or not 200 <= rcode < 300:
--> 362     raise self.handle_error_response(
    363         rbody, rcode, resp.data, rheaders, stream_error=stream_error
    364     )
    365 return resp

InvalidRequestError: Unrecognized request argument supplied: request_timeout
```

I tried reinstalling the llm and openai packages to no avail. Appreciate any guidance you might have.